# heroku console distinct not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I am new to ruby on rails environment.
I migrated my database to heroku along with the data using `seeds.rb`. in heroku server running `TableName.all` populates all data present in heroku postgres. when i try to run command like

```
TableName.select("Distinct(Category)")
```

i get error

```
Column TableName.Category does not exist.
```

i tried changin columns but didn't worked. please let me know what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

On my dev server it is working fine. there are no issues on dev site. i am using SQLite on DEv site

**EDIT****

Here is the Sequel text from:

```
  #rails console
    >>Recall.all
    SELECT "recalls".* From "recalls"
    =>[#<Recall id:1, Category: "******",......>]
>>Recall.select("Distinct(Category)")
SELECT DISTINCT(Category) From recalls
=>[#<Recall Category: "Foods">,#<Recall Category: "Consumer Products">]




    #heroku run console
    >>Recall.all
    SELECT "recalls".* From "recalls"
    =><Recall id:1, Category: "******",......>

>>Recall.select("Distinct(Category)")
Recall Load <2.5ms> SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM "recalls" 
PGError: ERROR: column "category" does not exist
LINE 1:SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM "recalls" 
                       ^
:SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM "recalls" 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR: column "category" does not exist
LINE 1:SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM "recalls" 
:SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM "recalls"
```

Comment: Please show the full text of the SQL that's getting run. You can get it from your Rails logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. it was escape sequence issue.
here is how i fixed that

```
Recall.select("DISTINCT(\"Category\")")
```

with reference to this question
[Rails and Heroku PGError: column does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902432/rails-and-heroku-pgerror-column-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't set up the database tables correctly on Heroku.  Did you do something like run `heroku run db:migrate`?

Why don't you investigate?  Have you tried `heroku pg:psql`? See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql).

Also, you really shouldn't be using SQLite - it's not the same database - and SQL is not standard across databases.  You'll run into a really subtle database bug at some point.